# Filling a variant array with charts in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a file that creates up to 120 charts based on data, variables, and format selections from the user. To do this I create a variant array to hold the charts which allows me to easily reference them for adding data, formatting, etc. This method has worked well for me so far.

Now I would like to let users make small tweaks to formatting (adjust the min and max on the axis, add or remove legend entries, etc.). To do this I would like to continue referencing the charts from an array, but I can't seem to add the existing charts to the variant array.

When I initially create the charts I use this line to add the chart to the array when it is created. I fill in appropriate parameters to place and size the chart and this seems to work fine.

```
Set charts(graphIndex) = activeSheet.ChartObjects.Add(...)
```

After creating all the charts, I think the non Global variables used are cleared from the cache (at least that is my current understanding). This means that in order to make these tweaks I need to reinitialize and redefine the variant array that I use to reference the charts. This is what I am struggling with. This is my current attempt to add the existing chart to the variant array.

```
charts(graphIndex) = Worksheets(activeSheetName).ChartObjects("chart name").Chart
```

When I run the code I am getting a "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support property or method."

Hopefully I provided enough context, but any help on this would be greatly appreciated. This feels like it should be fairly easy, but I couldn't find any information online.

Comment: Why not make your array a Global so it's preserved once the chart creation code ends? Aside from the missing `Set`, you sohlud note that in your first example you have an array of `ChartObject`, and in your second you would have an array of `Chart`: those are two different object types.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You are right, I did need to use `Set`. I am still fairly new to VBA and am teaching myself. Is `Set` always used for the `Variant` type or is it specifically used for object references? For the `Chart` vs. `ChartObject` I am still working out which one to use in a given situation. In this case I tried both to see if I could get it to work.

Comment: `Set` is for objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just guessing that in your code if you had the `Set` word it would have worked (However, I am not seeing the whole code, thus not sure).

---

This works, if you make sure to have 3 charts named "Diagramm 1", "Diagramm 2" and "Diagramm 3" on the first worksheet:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim cht2        As Chart
    Dim varArray    As Variant

    With Worksheets(1)
        Set cht2 = .ChartObjects("Diagramm 2").Chart
        varArray = Array(.ChartObjects("Diagramm 1").Chart, cht2)
        ReDim Preserve varArray(2)
        Set varArray(2) = .ChartObjects("Diagramm 3").Chart

        Dim cnt As Long
        For cnt = LBound(varArray) To UBound(varArray)
            Debug.Print varArray(cnt).Name
        Next cnt
    End With

End Sub
```

The `Reedim Preserve` increases the array units with one additional, while it keeps what it already has. Thus, at the end this is what we have in the locals:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response. Using `Set` seemed to be a big step forward, but I am still struggling to get the references to work correctly. My new code is: 

`Set charts(graphIndex)=Worksheets(activeSheetName).ChartObjects("chartname")`

It gets past that with no problems now (Thank you!). Unfortunately a few lines down I am now getting an error at

`numLegendEntries=charts(graphIndex).Chart.Legend.LegendEntries.count`

I know variables are all declared, but I am still getting an error.

Comment: Sorry, ignore comment above. I think this is a new issue unrelated to the original post. I think I should be able to work it out from here. Thank you.